# JPA - Joined table column in where clause does not filter

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Car
(
    id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , model    VARCHAR(25)        NOT NULL
  , make     VARCHAR(25)        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CarHistory
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , carId       INT REFERENCES car(id)       NOT NULL
  , action      VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL
  , actionDate  DATE                         NOT NULL
);
```

I need to get cars that have a history action of 'TRADED'. With SQL, I can do this by:

```
select c.*
from Car c
join CarHistory h on h.carId=c.id
where h.action='TRADED';
```

I have a Car entity and CarHistory entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data //lombok
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String model;
    private String make;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="carId", nullable=false)
    private List<CarHistory> carHistory;
}

@Entity
@Data //lombok
public class CarHistory {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String action;
    private Date actionDate;
}
```

I have the following `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    @Query(
            "SELECT c " +
            "FROM Car c " +
            "JOIN c.carHistory as hist " +
            "WHERE hist.action = 'TRADED' "
            )
    List<Car> findTradedCars();
```

But the above `@Query` returns CarHistory objects. I only need Car objects. And it even returns Car objects with CarHistory objects that have a action property of 'NEW', 'BOUGHT', etc.! Shouldn't it only return CarHistory objects that have a action of 'TRADED'?

How can I get only CarHistory objects with property of 'TRADED' in this query? Even better, is there a way to only get Car objects without the CarHistory objects (i.e. car.getCarHistory() is null)? I really only need CarHistory to filter out the Cars that I want (i.e. traded cars).

**Update**

I set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true` and now I see how this handled. First a select statement corresponding to the `@Query` is issued to get cars that have a car history with action of 'TRADED'. Then, when the car objects are returned in a `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class CarsController {

    @NonNull
    private final CarRepository carRepo;

    @GetMapping("/traded-cars")
    public List<Cars> getTradedCars() {
        return carRepo.findTradedCars();
    }

}
```

Jackson converts to JSON and in doing so reads the Cars' CarHistory property. That then causes a select statement to be issued for each car as follows:

```
select h.id, h.action, h.actionDate from CarHistory h where h.carId=?
```

Of note is that hibernate is getting the entire car history not just traded cars.

I suppose I could just set `@JsonIgnore` on carHistory prop within Car. Two questions still remain:

1. How would I be able to get carHistory items that are only 'TRADED'?
2. More Importantly, can I eliminate getting CarHistory objects altogether so that I don't have to annotate `@JsonIgnore`? I don't even need a CarHistory entity. Not sure if I can use CarHistory in JPQL if it's not an entity though. Perhaps, I have to use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a wrong query in your repository.
Below should work as expected:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c " +
       "JOIN c.carHistory as hist " +
       "WHERE hist.action = 'TRADED' "
)
```

Also, suggesting to put @ManyToOne in CarHistory for optimization:

```
public class Car {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private List<CarHistory> carHistory;
}

public class CarHistory {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId")
    private Car car;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ahsan Shah for catching this. `c.hist` was a typo. I've corrected in the OP.